# Find out type of VPN connections in network preference

Tags: network, vpn

I have a VPN connection in my system preference but I don't remember type of this connection (PPTP, IPSec etc). How do I find this out?

[image]

Comment: Netstat could tell you that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each kind will look slightly different in the Network System Preference Pane. Your "Home" connection appears to be PPTP. See below images for reference...

[image: L2TP]
[image: PPTP]
[image: IPSEC]

Comment: That's a good way of finding it out!